# How to use regex to remove the spaces between two rows?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

My Input file like this

```
Header1,,,,,,,,,,,
c1 , c2 , c3 ,,,,

 22-02-2017,1-2,10,,,,
 22-02-2017,2-3,11,,,,

 22-02-2017,4-6,10,,,,
 22-02-2017,5-8,11,,,,
```

I need to regex to achive below expected output:

```
Header1,,,,,,,,,,,
c1 , c2 , c3 ,,,,
22-02-2017,1-2,10,,,,
22-02-2017,2-3,11,,,,
22-02-2017,4-6,10,,,,
22-02-2017,5-8,11,,,,
```

I trying this regex for search \s\n in REplaceTExt and replacement value is \n.

After Replace text output content like below.,

```
Header1,,,,,,,,,,,c1 , c2 , c3 ,,,,22-02-2017,1-2,10,,,,22-02-2017,2-3,11,,,,22-02-2017,4-6,10,,,,
```

But my regex worked perfectly in regexr website.

http://regexr.com/3fbse

Is there is any other regex to search empty rows and combine rows before and after of empty rows?

Comment: What command are you using to edit the file? (ie. sed, perl,...)

Comment: No i m not using any command .i have just match that in regexr website only

Comment: So is your objective to edit the file or something else?

Comment: yes my objective is to edit the file

Comment: In that case, you can use sed and depending on whether there is any white space or not on the 'empty' lines you can use ^$ or ^[[:space:]]*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search:    `\n\n\s|\n\s`

Replace:    `\n`

[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com/3fbst)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could also try something like the following to search for empty rows and remove them.

```
regex search >> /\n+/g
replace with >> \n
```

see [demo](http://regexr.com/3fbsq)

Answer (score 1):

Sahil's solution is not as refined as it could be:

You can match with this pattern: `\n+\s` and replace with `\n`.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBY9Mr/1)

This will provide the same result with fewer steps.

The points to keep in mind with this very simple task is that using "alternatives" (pipes `|`) adds steps to your pattern and should be avoided when possible.

When alternatives are necessary, order the alternatives from shortest to longest -- this will provide greater efficiency.

Lastly, do not repeat characters in your pattern, use quantifiers -- this again improves performance.  When comparing `\n\n\s|\n\s` versus `\n{2}\s|\n\s`, the latter will outperform the former simply by using the `{2}` quantifier.

---

Probably the best advice would be to read your file with `file()` (which delivers an array of lines) and set the desired flags.

```
$array = file('yourfile.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

This prevents needing to perform the extra preparation step with regex or a replacing string function.

`fgetcsv()` is a great companion for this approach.