# Regex to remove blank lines

Tags: regex, unix, apache-nifi

I'm trying to remove the blank lines and the invalid records in the single regex . But it seems to be not working. In the below example, Records which contains Serverserial:0 and ServerName:"" empty are invalid records ,

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

By using the below Regex It removes only the invalid entries but will not remove the traces(blanklines)

```
.*(?<=ServerSerial":")0(?=").*|.*(?<=ServerName":")(?=").*
```

and tried this as well , No luck

```
.*(?<=ServerSerial":")0(?=").*[\r\n]*|.*(?<=ServerName":")(?=").*[\r\n]*
```

Current Output is like with blank lines

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},

{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},


{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

But the expected output is

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

Comment: `\r\n` is for windows, use `\n` for linux

Comment: didnt workout :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Method1: Using 1 ReplaceText processor:**

As i have used one of your regex that you have mentioned in the question.

Configure ReplaceText processor as

Search Value

```
(?<=ServerSerial":")0(?=").*[\r\n]*|.*(?<=ServerName":")(?=").*[\r\n]
```

Replacement Value

```
${literal("")} //as we are not having any capture groups so i have used empty value for replacing.
```

[image]

**Input:**

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

**Output:**

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

> **Method2: Using QueryRecord processor:**

If you know the schema of the data then you can use QueryRecord processor and then add new property in [QueryRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) processor as

```
select * from FLOWFILE where ServerName is not null and ServerSerial > 0
```

Then the processor outputs the flowfile with records that satisfies the above sql query.

> **Method3: Using 2 ReplaceText Processors in series:**

Use **ReplaceText** processor with below configs:

Search Value

```
\n+\s+
```

Replacement Value

```
shift+enter
```

Character Set

```
UTF-8
```

Maximum Buffer Size

```
1 MB //needs to change this values as per your flowfile size
```

Replacement Strategy

```
Regex Replace
```

Evaluation Mode

```
Entire text
```

[image]

I tried with the below data in my local instance

**input flowfile content:**

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},

{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},


{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

**output flowfile content:**

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/156985/replacing-blank-lines-in-a-file-using-a-efficeint.html) link for another approach to replace empty lines in the flowfile.

Comment: So do i need to use two ReplaceText , Is it possible to fix in a single Replacetext processor with regex

Comment: so it will degrade the performance right if we just use two RT processor

Comment: if you are dealing with millions of records

Comment: @Varshini  please check the update answer and use Method1 for your case and we need to use one ReplaceText processor..!!

Comment: Method 1 works fine , but it adds one empty line in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Append this to your second regex:

```
(?<=[\r\n])[\r\n]|
```

to remove blank lines by removing newline chars preceded by another new line.

Answer (score 0):

When you have (your file converted to) a unix file, you can use

```
grep -Ev 'ServerSerial":"0?"|ServerName":"0?"' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore those blank lines by following way.

Using ReplaceText processor.

```
Search:  \n\n\s|\n\s

Replace:  \n
```

http://regexr.com/3fbst

Reference : [How to use regex to remove the spaces between two rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384143/how-to-use-regex-to-remove-the-spaces-between-two-rows)

Let me know if you face any issues in it.

Answer (score 0):

If all your records are going be line based, this can be solved using Perl. Using a perl 
one-liner solution, we can use hex \x22 for double quotes. See, if the below works for you. I added blank lines additionally to your input.

```
>cat regex_event.dat
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},

{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},

{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
>
>perl -ne ' s/^\s*$//g; print if length($_) > 0 and not m/\x22ServerSerial\x22:\x220\x22,\x22ServerName\x22:\x22\x22/' regex_event.dat
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"XYZ_P_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691950","ServerName":"ABC_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"},
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1142691750","ServerName":"COL_P_1","deletedat":"2018-08-24 15:30:48.136"}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of NiFi 1.7.0 (via [NIFI-4456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4456)) you can configure a JsonTreeReader to read "one JSON per line" as your format is in. Then you can use QueryRecord to issue a SQL query to route the records however you like, for example an "invalid" property with query `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE ServerSerial = 0 AND ServerName = ""`, and a "valid" property with query `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE ServerSerial <> 0 OR ServerName <> ""`, or something like that.